# How to properly add a navigation drawer on an existing Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I already have built some activity on my app from scratch (empty view activity), It has a login and sign-up activity. Then I came up with the idea of adding a navigation drawer to the main activity after I logged in. The problem is, after following different tutorials that I found, Whenever I go to the main activity where the navigation is, the app crashes.

So this is my code, just found out that the reason why it crashes was after setting this part of the code (getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
)

Additionally this is the error that i am facing:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reviewerbot/com.example.reviewerbot.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object

```
package com.example.myApp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.usage.StorageStats;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.example.myApp.authHandler.User;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    User user = User.getInstance();
    TextView username;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = findViewById(R.id.txtMainUsername);
        username.setText(user.getUsername());// set username

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,R.string.menu_open, R.string.menu_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                System.out.println("id selected");
                System.out.println(id);
                if(id == R.id.navHome){
                    System.out.println("do something");
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


    }
}
```